# Feature Elimination from term document matix

Tags: python

I am new in python and trying to create term-document-matrix and identify the feature names from a sample array. I have managed to extract feature names and created the term document matrix out of it using preprocessing and CountVectorizer for sparse matrix representation as attached code in python.

## Sample array

```
doc=['I like databases', 'I like like databases','I am the not not the chalk']
```

### Preprocessing is done here before passing to sparse vector representation

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,2),lowercase=True, max_df=20)  # utf-8 default
# vectorizer.fit(MSG_train_Series)
document_term_matrix=vectorizer.fit_transform(MSG_train_Series)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print("get_feature_names():", feature_names)
print(" document_term_matrix:", document_term_matrix)
```

I am getting the output as below :

```
get_feature_names(): ['chalk', 'database', 'like', 'like database', 'like like']

document_term_matrix:   (0, 2)  1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 3)    1
  (1, 2)    2
  (1, 1)    1
  (1, 3)    1
  (1, 4)    1
  (2, 0)    1
```

Now I would like to eliminates features that occur in less than a given number of documents (say, chalk which occurs less than 2 documents)

Could anyone please do suggest me

Comment: See the [`CountVectorizer` documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), especially the `max_df` and `min_df` parameters.

Comment: Thanks ChrisP, I appreciate your help.